# Nomenclature for an alkane substituted with a branched alkyl group

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Consider, for example:

[image: 3-ethyl-2-methylpentane]

From what I've learned in chemistry class, this molecule would be unofficially named 3-isopropylpentane.

What would the official IUPAC name for this molecule be? And what's the general way to name these types of molecules?

EDIT: For this specific molecule, the naming can be simplified by looking at the main carbon chain differently.
For a more general case, consider heptane instead of pentane, in this case there's one chain that you're stuck with.

[image: another molecule]

Comment: 3-ethyl-2-methylpentane, also it would be propan-2-ylpentane and learn the IUPAC rules that's how to name all molecules.

Comment: @AS_1000 Wouldn't the name "3-ethyl-2-methylpentane"  suggest that there's 2 branches on the pentane chain, an ethyl on C3 and a methyl on C2 ? That's a different molecule. Also the name " propan-2-ylpentane" doesn't specify which of the pentane carbons is the propyl attached to..

Comment: @Chady are you sure it's a different molecule? Draw it out.

Comment: @Chady AS_1000 is correct. Once you have attached the isopropyl group, there is more than one possible chain of length 5, and one of those has a methyl at carbon 2 and an ethyl at carbon 3.

Comment: @AS_1000, orthocresol, Tyberius,  I see it now, it didn't occur to me to look at the chain differently.

Comment: But this only works in this specific case.. What if instead of pentane there was heptane ? There's only one chain to work with, how would the naming be done then ?

Comment: Related: [How should I name this branched alkyl substituent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/49058/7951)